# Error al convertir el informe a PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

Este es el mensaje que me sale

> ReportProcessingException: La definición de este informe no es válida
>   o no la admite esta versión de Reporting Services. La definición del
>   informe puede que se haya creado con una versión posterior de
>   Reporting Services, o que contenga contenido que no tiene el formato
>   correcto o que no es válido según los esquemas de Reporting Services.
>   Detalles: La definición de informe tiene un espacio de nombres de
>   destino no válido
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition'
>   que no se puede actualizar.

Solo me pasa cuando agrego parámetro al informe pero cuando creo un informe nuevo sin parámetro el código corre bien

```
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;
        byte[] reporte = null;

        decimal horaExtraTotal = 0;
        decimal horaDomingoTotal = 0;
        decimal horaTotalTotal = 0;
        int totalEmpleado = 0;

        var location = Session["Location"] as Location;

        ObjectParameter totalInactivo = new ObjectParameter("TOTAL_INACTIVO", typeof(int));
        ObjectParameter totalActivo = new ObjectParameter("TOTAL_ACTIVO", typeof(int));
        ObjectParameter totalLicencia = new ObjectParameter("TOTAL_LICENCIA", typeof(int));
        ObjectParameter totalVacaciones = new ObjectParameter("TOTAL_VACACIONES", typeof(int));


        var HoraExtra = chronecontext.SP_HORAEXTRA_EMPLEADO_LOCATIONID(Convert.ToInt16(location.LOCATION_ID), new DateTime(2019,4,1), new DateTime(2019,4,10), totalInactivo, totalActivo, totalLicencia, totalVacaciones).ToList();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Hora_Extra", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Domingo", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));

        foreach (var item in HoraExtra)
        {
            DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();
            rw["Id"] = item.ID_EMPLEADO;
            rw["Nombre"] = item.NOMBRE_EMPLEADO;
            rw["Hora_Extra"] = item.HORA_EXTRA.ToString();
            rw["Domingo"] = item.HORA_DOMINGO.ToString();
            rw["Total"] = item.TOTAL_HORA_EXTRA.ToString();

            horaExtraTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(item.HORA_EXTRA);
            horaDomingoTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(item.HORA_DOMINGO);
            horaTotalTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(item.TOTAL_HORA_EXTRA);
            totalEmpleado += 1;

            dt.Rows.Add(rw);

        }

        List<ReportParameter> reporteParametro = new List<ReportParameter>();

        reporteParametro.Add (new ReportParameter("Toral_Hora_Extra", "hola", false ));
        reporteParametro.Add(new ReportParameter("Total_Domingo", "fsasag", false));
        reporteParametro.Add(new ReportParameter("Toral_Total_Extra", "fafagag", false));

        ReportViewer report = new ReportViewer();
        report.Reset();
        report.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        report.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reporte/Report.rdlc");
        report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Hora_Extra", dt));
        report.LocalReport.SetParameters(reporteParametro);
        report.LocalReport.Refresh();
        reporte =  report.LocalReport.Render("PDF");

        return File(reporte, "application/pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el refresh, y te mando el fragmento de código que siempre uso.

```c#
 ReportViewer rptReporte = new ReportViewer();
            rptReporte.Reset();
            rptReporte.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ServerReport serverReport = rptReporte.ServerReport;
            serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials(usuario, password, dominio);
            serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(server);
            serverReport.ReportPath = reporte;

            ReportParameter ParametroGranja = new ReportParameter("Granja", granja.ToString(), false);
            ReportParameter ParametroPlantel = new ReportParameter("Plantel", plantel.ToString(), false);
            ReportParameter ParametroFecha = new ReportParameter("Fecha", Fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), false);

            serverReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] {
                ParametroGranja,
                ParametroPlantel,
                ParametroFecha
            });

            serverReport.Refresh();

            string extension;
            string encoding;
            string mimeType;
            string[] streams;
            Warning[] warnings;
            byte[] PDFBytes = serverReport.Render("PDF", null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out streams, out warnings);
            return PDFBytes;
```

Comment: Bueno no se  que  le pasa a mi código pero lo raro es que funciona hasta el momento que agrego un parámetro en el reporte hay deja de funcionar y la única forma que encontrado para que funcione borrar el informe y crear uno nuevo sin parámetro

Comment: Puse el codigo completo para que se pueda ver mejor

Answer (score 0):

En contre la solucion me falta el nuget microsoft.reportingservices.reportviewercontrol.webforms